# Problems with chef recipe

Tags: ruby, arrays, attributes, chef-infra

Sorry about my English.

Here is a ./recipes/default.rb

```
node['client-name'].each do |crontab|   
    item = data_bag_item('bag_name', "#{crontab}")

    node.default[:client_timezone] = "#{item['timezone']}"
    node.default[:client_name] = "#{crontab}"

    template "crontab" do
        path "/etc/cron.d/#{deploy}"
        source "default.erb"
        owner "root"
        group "root"
        mode "0644"
    end
end
```

The ./attributes/default.rb looks like this:

```
default['version'] = "1.0.0"
default['client-name'] = ['company_1','company_2']
```

The `templates/crontab.erb` looks like this:

```
30 04 * * * java -Duser.timezone=<%= node[:timezone] %> -jar /var/www/app-<%= node[:version] %>.jar /var/www/<%= node[:client_name] %>/config/spring/job.xml
```

My recipe puts two similar crontab files (company_1 and company_2) to /etc/cron.d/, but only for the last one attributes' value (company_2). Can you please tell me, where am i wrong?

Comment: And how looks the `crontab.erb`?

Comment: 30 04 * * * java -Duser.timezone=<%= node[:timezone] %> -jar /var/www/app-<%= node[:version] %>.jar /var/www/<%= node[:client_name] %>/config/spring/job.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the variables section of the `template` resource to assign the `client_name` and the `timezone` explicitly. The recipe might look like this:

```
node['client-name'].each do |client_name|   
    item = data_bag_item('bag_name', "#{client_name}")

    template "crontab" do
        path "/etc/cron.d/#{deploy}"
        source "default.erb"
        owner "root"
        group "root"
        mode "0644"
        variables ({
            :client_name => item['client_name'], # Don't you have this already?
            :client_timezone => item['client_timezone']
        })
    end
end
```

Your `crontab.erb` should look like this:

```
30 04 * * * java -Duser.timezone=<%= @client_timezone %> -jar /var/www/app-<%= node[:version] %>.jar /var/www/<%= @client_name %>/config/spring/job.xml
```

Comment: Thx, mate, that's exactly what i need. I'm very new in chef & ruby, so my questions might be a little bit retarded..